# Array length is not right when I call array.length

Tags: javascript

I am new to js and I am trying to make a loop that gathers movie titles from an api using jquery requests, and save the data in an array called arr like this:

```
  var arr = []

    var query = inp.value;
    var url = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${key}&query=${query}`
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
      var data = data.results;
      for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var title = data[i].original_title;
        arr.push(title)
      }
    });

  console.log(arr);
  console.log(arr.length);
```

The problem is when I try to print the new arr length is gives me a length of 0, why is this happening and how do I fix it?
[image]

Comment: You need to put the console inside the callback when the data is resolved. This is a classic async issue.

Comment: both console.logs are being executed before callback is resolved, so in that point length array is 0.

Comment: Duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/4642212).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you call `$.getJSON` it doesn't complete instantly. Your code below (outside of your `$.getJSON` callback) executes before the call has finished. Here is an example of what is happening.

```js
const arr = [];
$.getJSON('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1', (json) => {
  arr.push(json);
  console.log('First Log', arr.length);
});
console.log('Second Log', arr.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

To get the correct `arr.length` to log, you need to place them within your callback.

Example:

```
var arr = []

var query = inp.value;
var url = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${key}&query=${query}`
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
  var data = data.results;
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var title = data[i].original_title;
    arr.push(title)
  }
  console.log(arr);
  console.log(arr.length);
});
```

What isn't mentioned here is what you are trying to ultimately do. I would assume that you have the `arr` defined as a global variable for a reason. You may want to change your callback so that your code calls whatever subsequent *thing* that does something with the data returned from the API once the call is complete.

Comment: Great I just tried it and it works perfectly, thanks for the help!